# Unity3D 2018.2 running unusably slow in play mode on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

As stated in the title Unity is running EXTREMELY slow in play mode, however is perfectly fine in edit mode. I'm using an earl 2015 13-inch macbook pro with 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5, 8gb ram, and an Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB for graphics. Could it just be that my computer can't handle the CPU load? It will work ok when i have something like a rigid body sphere and a cube with collision but anything more seems to stop it completely. Any fixes for this or am I stuck? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Reduce graphics quality, your computer probably can't handle it especially without a dedicated gpu

Comment: What is "extremely slow"? < 1 FPS? 10 FPS? Were you able to run earlier Unity versions without trouble? I've been running earlier Unity builds on a mid 2012 MBP Retina (i7 vs. your i5) with a non-functional dedicated GPU (so using the Intel graphics) and can run Mapbox generated terrain with imported SketchUp models, trees, wind and full collision smoothly. Have you tweaked any of the graphics settings?

Comment: with a short movement script on low quality the rigidbody sphere won't even drop so it's not getting to a point where it's running. I'm new to unity so this is my first time running it, though a few of my friends who have experience with similar situations say this is out of the ordinary.